# Peace lily leaves with small, round bumps. Is this normal?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, peace-lily

My peace lily (purchased and repotted two months ago, kept in medium light environment in town with hard water) has some leaves exhibiting round bumps along the main stem. Is this normal? If not, what is the cause and how can I remedy it?

The peace lily itself seems a little droopy. Does anyone have any suggestions for reviving it a bit?

Thank you!

[image: round bumps on peace lily leaf]

[image: round bumps on peace lily leaf]

[image: droopy peace lily]

Answer (score 1):

I think that those are just blisters, they are caused by improper watering when the cells take in too much water and burst. The same thing happens on orchids.